# Iterate through a nested dictionary and incorporate instances where the key has a value of True into a print statement

Tags: for-loop, nested

Here is my dictionary with values that are in turn dictionaries themselves.

```
rarebirds = {
    'Golden-crested Toucan' : {
        'Height (m)': 1.1,
        'Weight (kg)': 35,
        'Color':'Gold',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Agressive': True
},
'Pearlescent Kingfisher': {
    'Height (m)': .25,
    'Weight (kg)': .5,
        'Color':'White',
        'Endangered': False,
        'Agressive': False
},
'Four-metre Hummingbird': {
    'Height (m)': .6,
    'Weight (kg)': .5,
    'Color':'Blue',
    'Endangered': True,
    'Agressive': False
},
'Giant Eagle': {
    'Height (m)': 1.5,
    'Weight (kg)': 52,
    'Color':'Black and White',
    'Endangered': True,
    'Agressive': True
},
'Ancient Vulture': {
    'Height (m)': 2.1,
    'Weight (kg)': 70,
    'Color':'Brown',
    'Endangered': False,
    'Agressive': False
}
}
```

Here is the `for` loop that is not working.

```
actions = ['Back Away',
    'Cover our Heads'
    'Take a Photograph']

for i in rarebirds: 
    if (i,'Aggressive')==True:
        print(i+": "+(actions[1]))
    else: print(i+ " is not aggressive")
```

It outputs

```
Golden-crested Toucan is not aggressive
Pearlescent Kingfisher is not aggressive
Four-metre Hummingbird is not aggressive
Giant Eagle is not aggressive
Ancient Vulture is not aggressive
```

But according to my dictionary the toucan and the eagle are aggressive so I want the `for` loop to print the index[1] of my list titled 'actions'. Not sure why the loop isn't successfully identifying the `True` boolean value.

Where am I going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

solved with

```
for i in rarebirds: 
    if rarebirds[i]['Endangered']==True:
        print(i+": "+ (actions[1]))
    else: print(i+ " is not aggressive")
```